# Full outer join does not show all values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables that I'm trying to join: a quote table, and a history table for the quote table - where I save updates in the quotes and deleted records.

What I need is a query to show all the records, separating it in 3 different status: Original (the first value of history table), History (the other modified values), and Current (values in my quote table).

My problem is: when I tried to full outer join both tables, the line with the current value (data that is in the quote table but not in the history table) does not appear when a history exist for this entry.
For example, if I have a quote where I updated the date from 1/1/2000 to 2/2/2000, my query will not return the line with 2/2/2000, just the history one (1/1/2000).

My quote table currently have 76 entries while the history have 11. When I run my query, it just return 81 values - the history table contains 6 different quotes.

What should I do to see all the values in the query?

SQL statement:

```
select case isnull(QDH_StatusID,0) when 1 then (case QDH_Date when (select top 1 QDH_Date from quotedeliveryhistory qdh2 where qdh2.QD_RecordID = QD.QD_RecordID order by QDH_Date) then 'Original' else 'History' end)
   when 2 then 'Deleted'
   when 0 then 'Current'
   End As 'Status',
   *
     from quotedelivery qd full outer join quotedeliveryhistory qdh
          on qdh.QD_RecordID = QD.QD_RecordID
```

Aditional information: the field QDH_StatusID just exist in the history table, and is used to control if the record was updated (1) or deleted (2). The field QDH_Date saves the date when the history was created (also just exist in the history table).

Comment: my thought is that original and history will apear on the same line, not on separate lines, because there is a complete match on your join criteria.

Comment: Does the QD_RecordID change when a date is updated?

Comment: QD_RecordID never changes. The history table contains values of updated records, so in the example that I gave in the question, the 2/2/2000 will only be in the original table while the 1/1/2000 will be saved in the history one.

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, it seems the results you get are correct and the query retrieves all the values from both tables. When you perform a `full outer join` you will get all the rows from both your tables `less` any rows that match the `join` condition (as they are shown only once), which is `81 = 76+11-6`.

Comment: I'm not a professional in SQL so you may be right, can you just help me to understand it? For example, the example that I used with the dates. In that case, the 1/1/2000 value is in my history table and the 2/2/2000 in my original table. Shouldn't I see both of them? Or because the field that I used to join (QD_RecordID) is equal it will not be displayed?

Comment: From what i can guess, you should see them on the same row. As you are selecting all the columns from both tables in your query.